FirstResponderView/FirstResponderIndexPath in TableView
I found when I put a webView on the screen and then click it, several properties in TableView including firstResponderView, FirstResponderIndexPath, and FirstResponderViewType have changed. These properties are hidden and I cannot change them. firstResponderView strong holds my cell, resulting in my cell not being able to call didEndDisplayCell when it slides out of the screen as expected.
Here is the breakpoint infos:
>_firstResponderIndexPath = (NSIndexPath *) 0xb58981baedfcad92
>_firstResponderView = (TBLVUpDownSwitchCell *) 0x15f8d0f00
firstResponderViewType = (int) 1

What should I do to avoid firstResponderView and firstResponderIndexpath from strong holding my cell, or what should I do to release it?
